# Showing $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ have a different number of subgroups of order $2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Looking at this example, can someone explain to me what is $_1$, $H_2$, $H_3$, and how they came about it?

[image]

Comment: $H_1,H_2,H_3$ are explicitly given. What do you not understand?

Comment: I understand that table given, but I do not understand how they got H1,H2,H3 and what exactly it means.

Comment: Well the easiest subgroups of a group are its cyclic subgroups. For example, the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ generated by $(1,0)$ is $\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$ (since $(1,0)+(1,0)=(0,0)$ we don't need any other summands).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is proving that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ are not isomorphic by identifying a property of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ that (a) is not true for $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and (b) is preserved under isomorphism (i.e., any group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ would also have this property).

The property used is the number of subgroups of order $2$.

If $\varphi$ is an isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ to another group $G$, and $H$ is a subgroup of order $2$ of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, then $\varphi(H)=\{\varphi(h):h \in H\}$ would be a subgroup of $G$.  So this property is indeed preserved under isomorphism.

How many subgroups of order $2$ does $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ have?  Three, as identified in author's notes, they are
\begin{align*}
 \{(0,0),(0,1)\}; \\
 \{(0,0),(1,0)\}; \\
 \{(0,0),(1,1)\}.
\end{align*}
There can't be any more, as there are no other elements in $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

How many subgroups of order $2$ does $\mathbb{Z}_4$ have?  One, namely
\begin{align*}
 \{0,2\}.
\end{align*}
Any subgroup containing $1$, would also contain $1+1=2$, $1+1+1=3$ and thus be $\mathbb{Z}_4$ itself.  Similarly any subgroup containing $3$ would be $\mathbb{Z}_4$ itself too.

We conclude that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ have a different number of subgroups of order $2$.  This proves they are not isomorphic.

Comment: Okay, I understand most of what's stated here.  Can you explain why there are three subgroups of order 2 for Z2 x Z2?  Is it because of the top row of the addition table?  I keep thinking there's only one subgroup, {0,0}

Comment: Because for subgroups of order 2 for Z6, would the subgroup be {0,2,4}?

Comment: We can check the group properties for $\{(0,0),(0,1)\}$ we can find it's a subgroup: it's closed under addition, addition is associative, there is an identity element, and each element has an inverse.  So it's a group, and a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, so it's a subgroup.

Comment: $\{0,2,4\}$ would be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_6$, but it has three elements, so it has order $3$.  On the other hand $\{0,3\}$ would be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ of order $2$.

Comment: So, an order of a certain number is just the number of elements in a subgroup?  Figuring out the actual numbers inside the subgroup has nothing to do with the order?  Such as, if I had {0,3,1,4,2} being a subgroup of Z5 of order 5?

Comment: I think I get this.  I'll read some more pdfs online, thanks.

Comment: The elements in groups don't even need to be numerical in any way (e.g. the group of rotations of a circle).  Groups such as $\mathbb{Z}_4$ tend to be written using numbers, since they relate to addition modulo $4$.  [The set $\{0,3,1,4,2\}=\{0,1,2,3,4\}=\mathbb{Z}_5$, so, yes, it's a subgroup of order $5$, but it's not a proper subgroup.]